# argc/argv in c linked list or binary tree

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

So I am trying to make a linked list/binary tree and:

The user should be able to choose the data structure directly from the command line when it starts the program. This should use the argc or argv arguments to main()

how would I do this? I don’t get it why not just use switch case statement asking the student.

```
     option 1: linked list 

     option 2: binary tree?
```

we didn’t really cover argc argv properly can anyone help?

Apparently its a duplicate ... hmm.. well i am asking specically about binary tree/linked list how would the user tell it to choose which data structure?

Comment: @Tormund Giantsbane Uhh no

Comment: @Coder That's a very sassy response to someone trying to help.  Perhaps you could expand on how Tormund's link does not answer your question.

Comment: sorry.. i updated it

Comment: Switch/Case and argc/argv are not either/or.  How do you expect your switch/case to get input from the user to indicate the type of data structure?

Comment: "...how would the user tell it to choose which one?" That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: you're too focused on choosing between a linked list or binary tree .. they may as well be choosing between bananas and umbrellas,, the point is you need to learn how to access and parse command line arguments. A menu-driven program, eg "Select an option:\n 1. Linked List\n 2. Binary Tree\n 3. Exit" will work just fine.

Comment: The "why not a menu" part: we know from experience that it is more efficient to pass the details of the task at hand on the command line, [preferably using a standard convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), than make everything menu-driven, because you cannot easily control chains and combinations of menu-driven utilities. You can with utilities that are controlled via command-line parameters. See [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well).

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane: Wrong programming language in the suggested duplicate: [tag:c] != [tag:c++]. While the explanation is the same for both languages, the examples in the answers are in C++, which may confuse those learners who do not immediately notice the different language tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experiment with the following skeleton program, and find out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s COMMAND\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "foo")) {
        printf("Doing foo.\n");

    } else
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "bar")) {
        printf("Doing bar.\n");

    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown command line parameter '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

The most common way to inform the utility user as to what to do, is to run the utility without parameters, or with `-h` or `--help` as the only parameter. (Windows command-line utilities might use `/?` or similar.)

Let's say the user can run the compiled program, `program` in the following ways:

```
./program list
./program tree
./program -h
./program --help
./program
```

where the first form tells the program to use a linked list; the second form tells the program to use a tree; and the other forms just output *usage*, information on how to call the program:

```
Usage: ./program [ -h | --help ]
       ./program MODE

Where MODE is one of:
    list    Linked-list mode
    tree    Tree mode

Further details on what the program actually does...
```

You achieve this with very little code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
    NO_MODE = 0,
    LIST_MODE,
    TREE_MODE
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int mode = NO_MODE;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        printf("Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s MODE\n", argv[0]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Where MODE is one of\n");
        printf("    list    for linked list mode\n");
        printf("    tree    for tree mode\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Further details on what the program actually does...\n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "list"))
        mode = LIST_MODE;
    else
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "tree"))
        mode = TREE_MODE;
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unknown MODE.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* mode == LIST_MODE or TREE_MODE here,
       depending on the first command line parameter.
    */

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that `||` operator is short-circuited in C: if the left side is false, the right side is not evaluated at all. So, above, the first `strcmp()` check is only done when `argv == 2`, and the second when `argv == 2` and the first `strcmp()` returned nonzero (no match).

In other words, the body of the *usage* section is only run when `argv != 2` (there is less than two, or more than two command line items, counting the program name as one); or if the sole command-line parameter matches either `-h` or `--help`.

`!` is the *not* operator in C. `!x` evaluates to `1` if and only if `x` is zero or NULL; and to `0` otherwise.

(You can confuse people by using `!!x`. It evaluates to zero if `x` is zero, and to one if `x` is not zero. Which is logical. It's often called the not-not operation.)

The `enum` is just there to remind you that magic constants are bad; it is better to use either enums, or preprocessor macros (`#define NO_MODE 0` and so on). It would be terribly easy to use `1` in one place to indicate *tree mode*, and `2` in another; such bugs are horrible to debug, needs way too much concentration from the human reading the code, to find such bugs. So don't use magic constants, use enums or macros instead.

Above, I decided that `NO_MODE` has value zero, and let the compiler assign (increasing) values to `LIST_MODE` and `TREE_MODE`; consider them compile-time integer constants. (Meaning, you can use them in `case` labels in a `switch` statement.)

Because `strcmp()` returns zero if the two strings match, `!strcmp(argv[1], "baz"))` is true (nonzero) if and only if `argv[1]` contains string `baz`. You see it all the time in real-world code when strings are compared.

If you look at my answers here, you'll very often see an `if (argc ...)` "usage" block in my example code. This is because even I myself will forget, often within days, exactly what the purpose of the program is. I typically have several dozen example programs on my machines I've written, and rather than looking at the sources to see if something jogs my memory, I simply run the example snippets without command-line parameters (or actually, with `-h` parameter, since some are *filters*), to see what they do. It's faster, less reading, and I'll find the relevant snippet faster.

In summary, write an *usage* output block in all your programs, *especially* when it is just a test program you won't publish anywhere. They are useful, especially when you have a library full of them, of various code snippets (each in their own directory; I use a four-digit number and a short descriptive name) that implement interesting or useful things. It saves time and effort in the long run, and anything that lets me be efficient and lazy is good in my book.

Comment: one question what is meant by the ! before stcmp

Comment: also before it even runs how would the user know what to type in? i cant execute code unless they type it exactly the same

Comment: @Coder: Let me know if you need further clarification. I decided to show an entire working example, even though there is a slight risk you might use it verbatim as your own work without understanding it; to make sure that does not happen, I made it clear your TA/teacher would catch you by simply asking one or two questions about it. All is explained in the text, and it's not hard at all, so if you bother to read the text, and understand how and why the code works, and why it should work that way, you're way ahead. It should be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

argc = argument count, argv = array of arguments. argv[0] is the executing program. argv[1..n] are the arguments passed to the executable.

Example: I call the executable foo with 2 arguments, bar and bas:
foo bar bas

argc = 3, argv = [foo, bar, bas]

Comment: how would the user choose binary tree or linked list?

Comment: Without seeing the requirements of your task, it's really up to how you organize and write your program and what you use the arguments for.

Comment: @Coder Expect the user to pass in a string or number representing the choice, then check what was given.

Comment: there are no requirements, it just says that so i have no idea where to start from or how the user would choose which data structure

Comment: So, if it were my task, I'd have the user pass an argument, say "1" or "2" for the choice of structure, then inside the program do a test/switch on that argument, most likely argv[1].